# What can happen if WantSamlResponseSigned = false

Tags: saml

In [SAML protocol](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/saml-protocol/saml-configuration-options/sign-and-encrypt-saml-requests), one can sign entire SAML response or just SAML assertion.

```
WantSamlResponseSigned=false, WantAssertionsSigned=true
```

Is there any difference in security?
What can happen if SAML response is not signed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I require IdP's to sign SAML2 SSO responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234618/should-i-require-idps-to-sign-saml2-sso-responses)