# In SAML Response should we sign Response or Assertion

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, signature, assertion, xml-signature

When returning SAML Response to SP, most IdP like AzureAD, Okta, Onelogin, GSuite have the following options about signature:

- sign Response
- sign Assertion
- sign Response and Assertion

And without any configuration, for most IdP, the default for signature is to only sign Assertion.

Below is a SAML Response example from AzureAD (the default signing option is sign Assertion). The Assertion is integrity protected and no tampering can be done. However fields other than Assertion, `Destination` `InResponseTo` `Issuer`, can be tampered with, or add/remove without knowledge!

[image]

So my question is:

1. Why there are 3 kinds of signing? (Response, Assertion, Response & Assertion)
2. In which use case should we choose to sign the whole Response, sign the Assertion or sign both Response and Assertion?
3. By only signing Assertion (as default by most IdP), do we exposed to any vulnerabilities?

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/13245092/4018180

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar Thanks for your comment! That's clear most of my question!!! I still wondering about when should we choose to sign Response or Assertion. It would be nice if it has some kinds of best practices. 

Can you make the above comment as an answer? I will accept it. Also, quote it just in case the referenced sof link gone 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [Scott's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636982/scott-t) answer from the [SOF post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234618/should-i-require-idps-to-sign-saml2-sso-responses/13245092#13245092)

> The only requirement for the IdP following the SAML 2.0 spec is to
> digitally sign the Assertion (see
> http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf
> section 4.1.3.5). That is enough to tell if the SSO operation from an IdP should be trusted by SP that has federated with it.
>
> Signing the outer Response is optional. There are some security
> benefits to it, such as preventing Message Insertion or Modification
> (see sections 6.1.3/6.1.5 in
> http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-sec-consider-2.0-os.pdf) - but in practice it's often omitted in lieu of relying on SSL/TLS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's clear most of my question! I still wondering about when should we choose to sign Response or Assertion though. It would be nice if it has some kinds of best practices.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-bestpractices/.  It may not specifically answer your question but it has all the best practices documented when dealing with XML Signature.

Comment: In the above mentioned link.... Section 3.2.1... Best Practice 15: Applications: Unless impractical, sign all parts of the document... If the service provider supports always sign the whole SAMLResponse.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Assertion is part of the SAML response, it would be enough to sign the SAML response only. This way you can secure/sign the entire SAML authentication response.

By signing assertions you only sign the attribute statement within the response.

By only signing assertions, I don't think that we expose to any vulnerabilities since the important information is within the assertions in SAML response.

Most of the IDPs have configuration options to handle signing as per the requirements in SP.Also if you are building your own IDP you can implement it to suppo

Comment: Yeah, I have the same thought on signing SAML Response. Just wondering why signing assertion exists :/

Comment: @truongnm Perhaps so that the assertion(s) can be stored and re-used in a different context?